# How do I specify multiple X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID while searching ebay products?

Tags: c#, ebay-sdk

How do I specify multiple X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID while searching for ebay products?

This is the link to the GlobalIDs.

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/Concepts/SiteIDToGlobalID.html

However, if I try to specify more than one I get exception "No such GlobalID".

I tried to give

```
1) "EBAY-US,EBAY-GB"
2) "EBAY-US;EBAY-GB"
3) "EBAY-US EBAY-GB"
```

None of them succeeded. Can anybody let me know how do I do that? I googled for this but even on google didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.
I don't think its designed to search more than 1 website at the same time.
But You can try to search 'x' times with a different global id.

This is how I used the ebay API (FindingAPI):

```
 ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        config.GlobalId = "EBAY-GB";
        config.EndPointAddress = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
        config.ApplicationId = Options.generalOptions.DeveleporKey;
        FindingServicePortTypeClient client = FindingServiceClientFactory.getServiceClient(config);
```

And this is what I used to make the search : 
`client.findItemsAdvanced(request);`

So you make different clients (1 US and  1 GB) and do something like : 
`var responseGB = GBclient.findItemsAdvanced(request);`

`var responseUS = USclient.findItemsAdvanced(request);`

Hope this helps, don't know what API you are using though.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly what your looking for, but if searching either globally, or in North America, or in Europe only, then you can use the ItemFilter tag specified to "LocatedIn".

It should search across the various sites specified.

Here is an [article](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1962) which goes into detail about it.